# How can I solve false duplicate in Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, ms-office

I recently switched to Mail.app from Outlook 2011 and have been importing some of my archive messages.  The problem is that for many of the messages, Mail.app seems to think they are duplicates so it only shows one of them.  However they are NOT duplicates, they are not even close.  All the messages are there, I can search in spotlight for them, however if i want to scroll through a folder they will not show up.  I can see certain messages have a '8 Duplicates' or similar written on the top right corner, and when you click that all the messages show, but it is only temproary, as soon as you move to a different folder and then come back all the messages are hidden again.

How can I turn this off?  And any ideas why Mail.app thinks the messages are duplicates?  they are on different dates, different subjects, 100% different as far as i can tell.

Comment: Is there another way to turn off duplicates? I already unchecked "include related messages" ages ago. I don't get many dups; it's not a bug, I just don't want them marked that way. I use the so-called duplicates to keep track of whether or not my email went through to a list (and then I only want to file one of them) or sometimes the duplicate is really to more than one separate list, and I need to file them in different places, keep track, etc. You can argue that I don't need to see them separate, but I want to. Any idea how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly enough, I can't help you on *why* Apple's Mail think your mails are duplicates.

I have two ideas to fix the problem though.

- Rebuild your Mailboxes (Select all your mailboxes, then in the Mailbox menu, choose rebuild). Wait the process to end completely (check nothing is being done in the Activity Window), then restart Mail;
- If this does not work, you can always disable the option that groups mails that are related (In the preferences, in Viewing, de-select "Include related messages"). This is not ideal as it disable one of the main features of Lion's Mail, but if it's buggy…